# How to do a DML upsert/insert loop in custom object after JSON deserialization?

Tags: webservices, dml, json, deserialize

I'm fairly new to Apex and I am completely at a loss at what to do next. So far I was able to grab and deserialize my JSON I grabbed from a Web Service(This does a GET Method for info for salespeople). Now what I want to do is that I want to insert (by dml & loop?) my deserialized Salesperson JSON into my SF Custom Object called: Salesperson__c. The fieldnames are the same. Any suggestions or especially example code will be helpful. Thank you, appreciate the help and input.

JSON below:

```
{
"Collection": {
    "Entities": [
        {
            "WineryId": "OWS",
            "Id": "JIM   ",
            "Name": "Jim Edmonds",
            "Street": "123 Wrecks St",
            "City": "Houston",
            "State": "TX",
            "Zipcode": "77001",
            "Telephone": "7135629245"
        },
        {
            "WineryId": "OWS",
            "Id": "CHOW ",
            "Name": "Robert Chow",
            "Street": "456 Checkers St.",
            "City": "Artesia",
            "State": "CA",
            "Zipcode": "90701",
            "Telephone": "5625552345"
        }
    ],
    "TotalCount": 2
}
```

}

My Class generated by JSON2Apex:

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

    public class WIMSGetSalesperson {

        public class Collection {
            public List<Entities> Entities;
            public Integer TotalCount;
        }

        public class Entities {
            public String WineryId;
            public String Id;
            public String Name;
            public String Street;
            public String City;
            public String State;
            public String Zipcode;
            public String Telephone;
        }

        public Collection Collection;


        public static WIMSGetSalesperson parse(String json) {
            return (WIMSGetSalesperson) System.JSON.deserialize(json, WIMSGetSalesperson.class);
        }

        static testMethod void testParse() {
            String json = '{\"Collection\":{\"Entities\":[{\"WineryId\":\"OWS\",\"Id\":\"JIM   \",\"Name\":\"Jim Edmonds\",\"Street\":\"123 Wrecks St\",\"City\":\"Houston\",\"State\":\"TX\",\"Zipcode\":\"77001\",\"Telephone\":\"7135629245\"},{\"WineryId\":\"OWS\",\"Id\":\"CHOW \",\"Name\":\"Robert Chow\",\"Street\":\"456 Checkers St.\",\"City\":\"Artesia\",\"State\":\"CA\",\"Zipcode\":\"90701\",\"Telephone\":\"5625552345\"}],\"TotalCount\":2}}';
            WIMSGetSalesperson obj = parse(json);
            System.assert(obj != null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you *do not* want to do DML in a loop. Thats an apex anti-pattern and will quickly run you afoul of governor limits.

What you need to do instead, is use a for loop to iterate over the collection of Entities building sObjects from them, and adding them to a list. then, with one dml call, insert that entire list. here's some psuedo code:

```
List<sObjectName__c> toInsert = new List<sObjectName__c>();
for(classname.entities e: collection.entities) {
  sObjectName__c n = new sObjectName__c();
  n.WineryId = e.WineryId;
  n.SomethingOtherThanID = e.Id;
  ...
  toInsert.add(n);
}
try {
  insert toInsert;
} catch(DMLException dmle) {
  // do something with the exception here
}
```

Comment: Note well, the bit about somethingOtherThanId there. You're Entity subclass has an Id field, but your sObject cannot include iD as a field for inserting